# Building toy package linking to Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I've been trying to build a dummy package following the book [Seamless R and C++ Integration with Rcpp](http://www.springer.com/statistics/computational+statistics/book/978-1-4614-6867-7)
This is essentially running a 1-liner:
`Rcpp.package.skeleton("mypackage")`

```
J:\R\tests>ls -rla mypackage
total 2
drwx------+ 1  mkpasswd   0 Jul 24 12:24 src
drwx------+ 1  mkpasswd   0 Jul 24 12:24 man
drwx------+ 1  mkpasswd   0 Jul 24 12:24 R
-rwx------  1  mkpasswd  54 Jul 24 12:24 NAMESPACE
-rwx------  1  mkpasswd 336 Jul 24 12:24 DESCRIPTION
drwx------+ 1  mkpasswd   0 Jul 24 12:24 ..
drwx------+ 1  mkpasswd   0 Jul 24 12:24 .
```

All works correctly and I then tried to install the newly-created package.

```
J:\R\tests>"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD INSTALL mypackage
```

this fails miserably

```
J:\R\tests>"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD INSTALL mypackage

package::utils loaded
LC_TIME have been set to C
Sourcing utility file : J:/R//utils/utils.R
Adding instantClient path: C:\instantclient\x64\instantclient_11_2 to PATH
Adding MOSEK: C:\Travail\Tools\mosek\7\tools\platform\win64x86\bin to PATH
J:/R//utils/descriptifTables.csv successfully loaded in a global data.frame descriptifTables

##------ [J:/R/tests] Wed Jul 24 12:26:42 2013 ------##
* installing to library 'J:/R/win-library/3.0'
* installing *source* package 'mypackage' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"J:/R/win-library/3.0/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c rcpp_hello_world.cpp -o rcpp_hello_world.o
Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")
make: *** [mypackage.dll] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mypackage'
* removing 'J:/R/win-library/3.0/mypackage'
```

I have been trying to do the same with Rstudio, the result is the same.
I have been building several other packages from sources (.tar.gz files) with not too many problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird errors. Can't think of much other than do not install R in a path with spaces -- recommendation of the "R on Windows FAQ" itself.

But this is clearly just an issue of your local  installation, so work through the Windows sections of Chapter 2 of the book.  That you have to call `R` as the weird `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\R.exe"` strongly suggests that you did not install R and Rtools as you were supposed to.

Comment: Tell my employer... each time I do something at home on Ubuntu or Mint it works out of the box, doing it on Windows 7 take unbounded amount of time.

Comment: I rarely ever work on Windows (even at the office) but when I do I know how to set a `PATH`. Ain't that hard, really, ...

Comment: `Sys.setenv(PATH="whatever")` in my `Renviron.site` file. I know, but may be it is not that easy...

Comment: That's just wrong and you got what you deserve.  You have to set the `PATH` **before you start the shell you are working in** i.e. set the `PATH` system-wide, and then start a new new `cmd.exe`.

Comment: I have no idea what you were just trying to say.  There are numerous tutorials out there about how to set up an R *compile environment* when on the development-unfriendly Windows platform.  Why don't you read one of those?

Comment: I was trying to say that setting PATH before starting the shell is not mandatory (http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html) though it helped finding the culprit. Thanks for your help

Comment: You are **[still wrong](http://www.cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset)** and you're looking in the wrong place. Let me quote: _This appendix contains a lot of prescriptive comments. They are here as a result of bitter experience. Please do not report problems to the R mailing lists unless you have followed all the prescriptions._

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34080/discussion-between-statquant-and-dirk-eddelbuettel)

Comment: No thank you. Not unless you change your handle / drop this 'I have to be anon. for professional reasons' nonsense.